# Jquery mmenu not working when two menu instances on the same page

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I'm using the plugin **mmenu** (http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) to create slide-out menus on a site. I have created both left and right-side menus.
On page load I'm initializing my two menus like this:

```
$('#burger-menu').mmenu();

$('#twitter-tab').mmenu({
position: 'right'
});
```

When I do so, both menus display incorrectly when they are activated. The right one (twitter) slides open but I get two (nested) "mm-page" wrappers around my content instead of the normal one, each of which is slid to the left by the designated offset amount, so I see an extra layer and extra shadow effect when it's open. The left one (burger) just gives me a totally blank page, though I can see I'm also getting two "mm-page" wrappers around the page content.

If I disable either one of the above initializers, the remaining menu functions perfectly.

Is there some trick to using mmenu with multiple menus on the same page? I haven't found anything in the documentation or on StackOverflow or elsewhere online.

Comment: Same problem here, except I am using a JQuery Mobile multipage setup.

Answer (score 1):

As the "advanced" example in the download pack (or in the phone-frame on the website) has two working menus on one page, I think it's an issue with how you've setup your HTML or maybe how you've configured the plugin.

Try the tutorial on how to setup the HTML:
http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/tutorial.php